# Automatically refreshing (not just tailing) a file in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have a process that outputs text to a file `output.log` . Sometimes this process deletes the file and starts over.

I would like to keep track of the contents of this file within Emacs automatically. I have used `auto-revert-tail-mode` before, but this **appends** new output to the buffer, displaying content that may not be in the file anymore (e.g. because the processes deleted the previous file and created a new one).

The only command that seems to do the job is `C-x C-v RET` (which calls `find-alternate-file` on the original filename), but I have to type this manually.

Does Emacs provide any built-in mechanism to keep track of the contents of a file? Or perhaps there is a way to have `auto-revert-tail-mode` add some marker to indicate when the file was deleted and re-created from scratch?

Comment: Emacs never ceases to amaze me. Just this weekend I learned you can do IRC in it, now I see it replaces `tail -f`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`M-x auto-revert-mode` should do what you are looking for. It updates the content of the file.

Also when you feel that you have to do manually, you can use emacs macro  (M-x kmacro-start-macro) and bind it to a key.

Answer (score 3):

There is also `M-x global-auto-revert-mode` that applies `auto-revert-mode` to all new buffers, in case you forget it. You can set it in `.emacs` with `(global-auto-revert-mode 1)`